# simple angularjs app, but I'm getting {{ this should be the data }}

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

simplest angularjs app

I've create asp.net mvc4 app and I'm installed angularjs package from nuget. 
Layout.cshtml is cleared  and it's looked like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/AngularJSApp/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="homeController" class="container body-content">
        {{ testData }}
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created main.js where I stored module and correspoding controller, just simple one

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");

app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testData = "this is test data";
}]);
```

I've double checked file references from _Layout.cshtml (both .js files are loaded)

but on rendering page I'm getting `{{ testData }}`  instead of actual data.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: var app = angular.module("myApp") is this where you create your module?

Comment: You may not have noticed but AngularJS will output a link or links to the console that links back to AngualJS errors documentation, in your case above you should get a link To error:nomod https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp and that page will explain the common cause of this error and some uncommon ones!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare module, you should use:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

This notation:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

could be used later to retrive that module and append stuff to it

The more other modules you will need, you can inject them into that array, e.g.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this in your main.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

You are missing the second parameter of the `module` method

[Angular module reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)